# Google Translation API time format not correct

Tags: google-translation-api

Is there a way to specify time format.

If i try to translate "The time is 10:10 am" then 10:10 gets replaced with 10h10.

**:** is replace with **h**. Is there a way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: could you add some reproduction code for this? I did not find any issue in Translate API [here](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=ga&text=The%20time%20is%2010%3A10%20am%0A%0A&op=translate&hl=en)

Comment: See here we are translating from English to French. Added picture